# How to overlay layout in side list view item android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-overlay

I have a ListView backed up by a BaseAdapter. The layout that I'm using is a RelativeLayout with some TextViews and ImageViews that are rendering ok. The problem is that I want to overlay anther layout with top of select  list view item with match the parent height and width, and background color transparent. How to do it ?

> [image]

Comment: You can try `<framelayout>` to wrap the two views you want to overlay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your root layout must be FrameLayout.

```
<FrameLayout>

   <RelativeLayout>
       <!-- This is your existing relative layout -->
   <RelativeLayout>



   <AnyLayoutHere>

       <!-- This will be your overlay that you can hide or show -->
   </AnyLayoutHere>



</FrameLayout>
```